# Как добавить существующие ключи в xcode

Tags: ios, key

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Совсем не знаком с разработкой под ios, срочно поступила задача пезалить проект на test flight. Доступ к сертификатам имеется, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый - запросить экспортировать нужные сертификаты у создателей и импортировать себе (потом перезапустить Xcode)

Вариант второй - отозвать один из перечисленных сертификатов и создать со своим запросом сертификата.